# In openbmc what is the difference between the xyz path and the /redfish/v1 path

Tags: rest, openbmc

I am new to openbmc and trying to understand the basic details.
As I am checking docs, I found two docs, REST-cheatsheet.md & REDFISH-cheatsheet.md

They both are using the curl to get and set the entries in openbmc.
But, the path used is different.
REST-cheetsheet.md uses, xyz/openbmc_project as path but REDFISH-cheatsheet.md uses redfish/v1/ as path to get details.

If we get same details with both what exactly is the difference??
ALso I need to populate the /redfish/v1 details, how to do that??

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

When OpenBMC first started, Redfish had fairly minimal industry buy-in so OpenBMC made a dection to make a custom REST API to manage itself. This is the "REST-cheatsheet". After a few years, Redfish via the DMTF began to mature and get a lot more industry buy-in. The decision was made within the OpenBMC community to deprecate the REST interfaces and move to being a Redfish managed system.

There's actually a commit up for review that would disable the REST based interface by default (https://gerrit.openbmc-project.xyz/c/openbmc/bmcweb/+/29344).

Try and utilize Redfish for any work you're doing, it's the direction of OpenBMC from an out of band management perspective.

Answer (score 0):

**Redfish** is defined and secure.

The REST API is deprecated, mostly; just go with the future and that is **Redfish**.